# Convert ArcGIS Javascript api Geometry Object to GeoJson

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geojson

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert ArcGIS Server JSON to GeoJSON?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13029/how-to-convert-arcgis-server-json-to-geojson)

How to convert ArcGIS Javascript api Geometry Object to GeoJson using Javascript?

Comment: This looks similar to the question I asked here:
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13029/how-to-convert-arcgis-server-json-to-geojson

Comment: @Tanner good call, I voted to close this as an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it client-side in JavaScript. You can check the source out here.
https://github.com/odoe/esritogeo

And I've started implementing the same thing in python, but in both directions.
https://github.com/odoe/SpatialJSON

Here is a sample where you can use JavaScript to convert the results of an Esri map service query to GeoJSON to use in Leaflet
https://gist.github.com/2424223

Answer (score 0):

The geometry object has a method, toJson(), that will do this for you:
[Javascript API Reference](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jsapi_start.htm)

Comment: That method generates an object. It doesn't generate an object that conforms to the GeoJSON spec.

Comment: Yes,toJson() method will return EsriJSON.But I want GeoJSON format.