# ArcGIS REST export map features as geoJSON

Tags: openlayers-2, arcgis-rest-api

Is it possible to export the features from a map as geoJSON using an ArcGIS REST service?  I'm trying to make a vector layer in OpenLayers based on the output from the map's present view based on a layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly, no (see [Sean Gillies Blog](http://sgillies.net/blog/1045/why-not-geojson/) for some reasons why). To do what you're after the easiest way is to convert from ESRI JSON to geoJSON with some intermediate script/service. See the [How to convert ArcGIS Server JSON to GeoJSON?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13029/how-to-convert-arcgis-server-json-to-geojson) question on this site for a variety of different ways to do this.

Answer (score -4):

One way to publish GIS feature services is to use cartoview www.cartologic.com/cartoview the Cartoview installer will also install GeoNode on windows. After the installation you can download and install the ArcGIS feature server app to serve out Feature services. This way you will be able to serve both standard WMS and geojson as well as feature services from the same platform, which will open the door to work with openlayers or ESRI apps

Comment: Are you associated with cartologic?

Comment: I work for Cartologic

Comment: From http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59302: The community generally frowns on overt self-promotion and tends to vote it down and flag it as spam, so be careful. Post good, relevant answers, and if they happen to be about your product, so be it. However, you must disclose your affiliation with the product in your answers. Also, if a huge percentage of your posts include a mention of your product, you're clearly here for the wrong reasons. Our advertising rates are quite reasonable; contact our ad sales team for details. We also offer free vote-based advertising for open source projects.