# ShapeFile or feature class to json

Tags: shapefile, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, convert, json, arcgis-desktop

Is there any online or desktop based tool that can convert shapefile or feature class to json and not Geojson.Is there any tool in arcgis desktop to convert shapefile or featureclass into json.

Comment: My understanding is that GeoJSON is just a subset of JSON (for example, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618726/convert-json-to-geojson) so can you elaborate on what flavour of JSON you are wanting to write spatial features to instead of GeoJSON, please?

Comment: I just want construct the feature collection then feature layer out of it in arcgis javascript Api.

Answer (score 2):

ArcGIS's JSON is specific to ArcGIS server. Still you have a few options:

1. If you can get access to ArcGIS server, publish a map service with your data as a feature service. You can then query the REST end point, and get it is JSON format.
2. ArcGIS Online has a 30 day trial. You can do something similar there. (I am guessing here. I personally have not used ArcGIS online so far.)
3. Convert your shape file to geoJSON. Convert that to ArcGIS JSON, as explained in [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13029/how-to-convert-arcgis-server-json-to-geojson). You could also look at this [ticket](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/attachment/ticket/3661/EsriGeoJSON.js) on OpenLayers, on how it can be done in Javascript.

Comment: I think this is not the solution as Arcgis server is itself heavy application and needs Geodatabse.

Comment: If you want the answer to be a lightweight software that does this for you, you'll have to write one yourself. Currently excluding ArcGIS Server no COTS or OSS does this for you in one step.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply @Devdatta Tengshe I got how to do it.

Comment: @Gunner If my question has helped you, please mark it as accepted. Otherwise if you have found a better way, please consider sharing it, so as to help others in the future.

Answer (score -1):

Well Open Source tools like Postgis, Postgresql and Mapserver with gdal can be used todo those kind of convertions but they are out of ArcGis.

If you known about the argis programming language, it is called AVL I guess( I not an arcgis user ) you could write a procedure to do that. But going out of GeoJSON would be strange since a JSON without Geo could not be rendered, that is why it is called GeoJSON. I guess you want a simple feature attribute translation.

Comment: AVL? Do you mean Avenue? Or Arc Macro Language? Also OP was talking of ArcGIS Server's JSON format, which is quite different from GeoJSON, but nonetheless contains Geographic locations.

Comment: I guess you write on language name avenue.