# JSON rings data to PostGIS

Tags: python, postgis, postgresql, psycopg2

Pulling data from a arcgis web query and using python/psycopg2 to insert it into postgreSQL. Here is one of the geometry attributes

```
js = json.dumps(i['geometry']['rings'])
```

this line prints

```
[[[336618.9998379126, 642371.4375939071], [336323.46893291175, 642018.6873151585], [336115.2813571617, 642248.7498471588], [336121.53134466335, 642254.3751639873], [336137.81248007715, 642268.6251354888], [336154.3436149955, 642282.6247794032], [336171.1250774972, 642296.2500802353], [336188.1558833271, 642309.6873893216], [336205.40617691353, 642322.7500272393], [336222.87497399375, 642335.500001736], [336240.56260266155, 642347.9999767393], [336267.0937175788, 642365.4999417365], [336292.5624986626, 642381.6872453243], [336318.28127924725, 642397.4375419021], [336344.2815553285, 642412.6875114068], [336370.56267074496, 642427.4998177364], [336397.0937856622, 642441.875117071], [336401.7814403288, 642443.8747849911], [336406.43759899586, 642445.937444903], [336411.06258974597, 642448.062768735], [336415.6564125791, 642450.3127642423], [336420.1875714958, 642452.6874314025], [336424.68756249547, 642455.0624266565], [336429.1560574956, 642457.5624216571], [336433.56254474446, 642460.1250805706], [336437.93753599375, 642462.7500753254], [336442.25019141287, 642465.4377339855], [336446.5313508287, 642468.2500643209], [336450.7813423276, 642471.0623946562], [336454.93750199676, 642474.0000528246], [336459.06249374524, 642477.0000468194], [336463.12514966354, 642480.062704742], [336467.15630957857, 642483.2500343248], [336471.1251336634, 642486.4373639077], [336475.03129382804, 642489.7500213236], [336478.8747900799, 642493.0626787394], [336482.6562785804, 642496.5000078231], [336486.37510316074, 642500.0000008196], [336490.0627598278, 642503.5623296574], [336491.18742949516, 642504.6876554862], [336618.9998379126, 642371.4375939071]]]
```

When I manually download this shapefile the geometry type is MultiPolygon.

the below code is within a for loop.

```
js = json.dumps(i['geometry']['rings'])
osc =  i['attributes']['OS_CLASS']
qry = "insert into preserve (os_class,geom) values(%s,ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText(%s),3424));"
cur.execute(qry,(osc,geojson2))
conn.commit()
```

this is the error i get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<module1>", line 22, in <module>
InternalError: parse error - invalid geometry
HINT:  "{"" <-- parse error at position 2 within geometry
```

this `js = json.dumps(i['geometry'])` prints

```
{"rings": [[[336618.9998379126, 642371.4375939071], [336323.46893291175, 642018.6873151585], [336115.2813571617, 642248.7498471588], [336121.53134466335, 642254.3751639873], [336137.81248007715, 642268.6251354888], [336154.3436149955, 642282.6247794032], [336171.1250774972, 642296.2500802353], [336188.1558833271, 642309.6873893216], [336205.40617691353, 642322.7500272393], [336222.87497399375, 642335.500001736], [336240.56260266155, 642347.9999767393], [336267.0937175788, 642365.4999417365], [336292.5624986626, 642381.6872453243], [336318.28127924725, 642397.4375419021], [336344.2815553285, 642412.6875114068], [336370.56267074496, 642427.4998177364], [336397.0937856622, 642441.875117071], [336401.7814403288, 642443.8747849911], [336406.43759899586, 642445.937444903], [336411.06258974597, 642448.062768735], [336415.6564125791, 642450.3127642423], [336420.1875714958, 642452.6874314025], [336424.68756249547, 642455.0624266565], [336429.1560574956, 642457.5624216571], [336433.56254474446, 642460.1250805706], [336437.93753599375, 642462.7500753254], [336442.25019141287, 642465.4377339855], [336446.5313508287, 642468.2500643209], [336450.7813423276, 642471.0623946562], [336454.93750199676, 642474.0000528246], [336459.06249374524, 642477.0000468194], [336463.12514966354, 642480.062704742], [336467.15630957857, 642483.2500343248], [336471.1251336634, 642486.4373639077], [336475.03129382804, 642489.7500213236], [336478.8747900799, 642493.0626787394], [336482.6562785804, 642496.5000078231], [336486.37510316074, 642500.0000008196], [336490.0627598278, 642503.5623296574], [336491.18742949516, 642504.6876554862], [336618.9998379126, 642371.4375939071]]]}
```

I am unsure of how to manipulate the data and which postgis function to use to insert it into postgresql. I also do not know what the data type rings means

here is a link to the data http://geodata.state.nj.us/arcgis/rest/services/Applications/NJ_Highlands/MapServer/34/query?where=OS_CLASS+%3D+%27MUNICIPAL%27&text=&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryPolygon&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&outFields=&returnGeometry=true&returnTrueCurves=false&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&returnDistinctValues=false&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&f=pjson

Additionally, I have used the ST_GeomFromText function but I got the same error

**UPDATE**

got this too run and the layer is now in postgresql. However when I try and bring the data into QGIS nothing shows up at all. The coordinates seem to be NJ state plane, which is SRID 3424.

```
js = json.dumps(i['geometry']['rings'])
data = {"type": "MULTIPOLYGON",
    "coordinates":js}
osc =  i['attributes']['OS_CLASS']
qry = "insert into preserve (os_class,geom) values(%s,ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(%s),3424));"
cur.execute(qry,(osc,json.dumps(data)))
conn.commit()
```

Comment: why is this array elements deep? eww.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bunch of things...

## That's not GEOJSON

That's actually an obscure and proprietary [ArcGIS api](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/geoenrichment/api-reference/input-polygons.htm). There are ways to [handle that if you want (which may be a better idea than my quick and dirty solution).](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/13029/6052) Just to get it out of the way, I already tested on your REST url that you provided `f=geojson` is not supported (ArcGIS REST API did not enable it or is otherwise too old).

## We can read the ArcGIS in PostgreSQL too

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_MakeLine(
  ST_MakePoint((element->0)::text::double precision, (element->1)::text::double precision)
  ORDER BY elementord
))
FROM (
  SELECT $$[[[336618.9998379126, 642371.4375939071], [336323.46893291175, 642018.6873151585], [336115.2813571617, 642248.7498471588], [336121.53134466335, 642254.3751639873], [336137.81248007715, 642268.6251354888], [336154.3436149955, 642282.6247794032], [336171.1250774972, 642296.2500802353], [336188.1558833271, 642309.6873893216], [336205.40617691353, 642322.7500272393], [336222.87497399375, 642335.500001736], [336240.56260266155, 642347.9999767393], [336267.0937175788, 642365.4999417365], [336292.5624986626, 642381.6872453243], [336318.28127924725, 642397.4375419021], [336344.2815553285, 642412.6875114068], [336370.56267074496, 642427.4998177364], [336397.0937856622, 642441.875117071], [336401.7814403288, 642443.8747849911], [336406.43759899586, 642445.937444903], [336411.06258974597, 642448.062768735], [336415.6564125791, 642450.3127642423], [336420.1875714958, 642452.6874314025], [336424.68756249547, 642455.0624266565], [336429.1560574956, 642457.5624216571], [336433.56254474446, 642460.1250805706], [336437.93753599375, 642462.7500753254], [336442.25019141287, 642465.4377339855], [336446.5313508287, 642468.2500643209], [336450.7813423276, 642471.0623946562], [336454.93750199676, 642474.0000528246], [336459.06249374524, 642477.0000468194], [336463.12514966354, 642480.062704742], [336467.15630957857, 642483.2500343248], [336471.1251336634, 642486.4373639077], [336475.03129382804, 642489.7500213236], [336478.8747900799, 642493.0626787394], [336482.6562785804, 642496.5000078231], [336486.37510316074, 642500.0000008196], [336490.0627598278, 642503.5623296574], [336491.18742949516, 642504.6876554862], [336618.9998379126, 642371.4375939071]]]$$::jsonb->0
) AS t(json)
CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(json)
  WITH ORDINALITY
  AS jae(element,elementord);
```

Here we're

1. Casting the text string as binary json and drilling down a level with `::jsonb->0`
2. Turning the JSON into a result set.
3. Making an `ST_Point` out of the array by `ST_MakePoint`ing the first element the `x` cord, and the second element the `y` cord.
4. Calling the aggregate version of `ST_MakeLine` to make a line.
5. Displaying it as text to show it's done.

## We can also read the ArcGIS KMZ

That REST URL you provided (nice question) supports `.kmz`. You may find it better to download that and unzip it. Then you have to extract just the geometry component and use [`ST_GeomFromKML`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromKML.html)

> ST_GeomFromKML works only for KML Geometry fragments. It throws an error if you try to use it on a whole KML document.

Comment: thanks for the response. i couldn't find anything on 'rings' data type. as for the SQL, your answer is a tad bit over my skill level. why do you use a cross join? and the what exactly does lateral do?

Comment: A `CROSS JOIN` is a method in SQL that explicitly multiplies the rows. It's clear then that what we're doing is generating a *Cartesian product*. If I put it in the `SELECT` clause which I can do, the ordering is unspecified and the intent is harder to infer. This way. You see I'm selecting 1 row (from values), and the multiplying that by the result of `jsonb_array_elements(row)` and I'll have rowct1*rowct2 total rows. The select is just changing what is return. Not the quantity.