# Opening ArcGIS webmap json file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, compatibility

I have a json file downloaded from the ArcGIS website.
You can simply view it in the browser at this address:
https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/content/items/31c5019cf5104960b50f31362d0d8196/data

I would like to load the data into QGIS. It doesn't seem to be compatible...

I used the `ogr2ogr` command but with no result.

Comment: i just ran into your problem last night, check out my question and the answer http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/224190/json-rings-data-to-postgis

Comment: this one may help as well http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13029/converting-arcgis-server-json-to-geojson

Comment: Sounds like 'ESRI GeoJSON' aka ESRI GeoServices JSON