# Incomplete data from ArcGIS REST API query

Tags: arcgis-rest-api

Using an ArcGIS REST API call, I'm trying to access the Houston 311-reports public data (https://www.houstontx.gov/311/). Following [Extracting data from ArcGIS REST endpoint?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/252425), I created a query that returned incomplete data. To elaborate, it returned only the status (i.e., Active or not) and the location of the report. Additional data (say, the type of report, time stamps etc.) that are available in the 311 dashboard are missing.

I tried different queries using the variables in the data (e.g., Status=Open), and the queries returned error code 400. I'm not sure if I'm trying to access the wrong API or if there are mistakes in my API call.

Query: https://mycity2.houstontx.gov/pubgis01/rest/services/311/D365_SR311_PROD/MapServer/1/query?&where=ObjectID%3E=1000+and+ObjectID%3C1999&f=json

Data homepage: https://mycity.maps.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=278ec211ab53471d950ed224540c00c7

Comment: Your query returned results for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return all Active 311 reports you can use

> &havingClause=**StateCodeName**%3D%27**Active**%27

```
https://mycity2.houstontx.gov/pubgis01/rest/services/311/D365_SR311_PROD/MapServer/1/query?where=1%3D1&text=&objectIds=&time=&timeRelation=esriTimeRelationOverlaps&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&distance=&units=esriSRUnit_Foot&relationParam=&outFields=&returnGeometry=true&returnTrueCurves=false&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&havingClause=StateCodeName%3D%27Active%27&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&historicMoment=&returnDistinctValues=false&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&returnExtentOnly=false&sqlFormat=none&datumTransformation=&parameterValues=&rangeValues=&quantizationParameters=&featureEncoding=esriDefault&f=geojson&as_sfid=AAAAAAW2hpHn5EuUvqECWEauZDCRV2dU6NxTVn_9o4BuJ3-tPmFu4Khw1xULw886p6AW6s-yo6Y-osUmTFldSol2eAekwxzxSQRgUmvGf8VgYb4KdbtB_2z5zTJtLt7DrhRwBU8%3D&as_fid=35db37329ad918c84713150bbf9325e724ddec5b
```

You can build your own query here
https://mycity2.houstontx.gov/pubgis01/rest/services/311/D365_SR311_PROD/MapServer/find