# Transforming Esri JSON to Shapefile without using ArcPy?

Tags: shapefile, geojson, json

I have a [large ESRI json](http://arcgis-v4fixr2-658801079.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/arcgis/rest/services/GMI/NoCache/MapServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&text=&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&outFields=&returnGeometry=true&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=*&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&returnDistinctValues=false&returnTrueCurves=false&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&f=pjson) (which I got from a request at an [ESRI Rest API](http://arcgis-v4fixr2-658801079.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/arcgis/rest/services/GMI/NoCache/MapServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&text=&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&outFields=&returnGeometry=true&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=*&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&returnDistinctValues=false&returnTrueCurves=false&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&f=html)) that I need to convert to some sort of vector file, preferably a Shapefile.

It seems there are [ways of doing this using ArcPy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13029/converting-arcgis-server-json-to-geojson), but I do not own an ArcGIS license. Is there a way to work around this or is ArcGIS the only way to do it?

Comment: Use GDAL. Ogr2ogr http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html and esrijson driver  http://www.gdal.org/drv_esrijson.html. In released versions ESRI json is read with the GeoJSON driver but from user point of view it does not make sense.

Comment: @user30184 Thanks for your reply. I'm still a bit confused since I don't have a deep understanding of GDAL beyond a little "rgdal" in R.

1.- The ESRI json driver seems to be available only on **GDAL 2.3** but the latest released version is **2.1**, if I'm correct. How could I use an unreleased version? (I'm using MacOS)

2.- You stated that in released versions of GDAL, ESRI json files are read with the GeoJSON driver. I tried doing that in R (with the "rgdal" package function "readOGR()") which has the GeoJSON driver, but I'm still unable to read the file.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share some small sample of data?

Comment: Or try yourself. Download some data and run ogrinfo your_file.json.

Comment: @user30184 [Here is the result of a query for one polygon](http://arcgis-v4fixr2-658801079.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/arcgis/rest/services/GMI/NoCache/MapServer/0/1000?f=pjson). I tried saving it as JSON and running ogrInfo on it (in R)  but I get  or "Cannot open data source", or "Cannot open layer" if I specify the layer name as the file.

Comment: I would send mail to gdal-dev mailing list. Perhaps this json file is somehow special.

Comment: Did you try exactly that response. With this result, it is a strong job to guess the right geometry type and srs. If you look on drv_esrijsom.html page they use, a layer query result, which also returns the layer structure.