# Converting ESRI JSON to GeoJSON

Tags: arcgis-server, geojson, arcgis-online, json

I am having trouble converting an ArcGIS Online JSON output to a more standard GeoJSON format. I have [tried the solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13029/converting-arcgis-server-json-to-geojson) in this thread, but the answer is either deprecated or no longer working. Every other solution I've come across seems to require an ArcGIS license - there must be an open source tool for this conversion, right?

And yes, I've tried modifying the `'f'` query parameter to `'geojson'` to no avail. The data is from 2014, so I guess this functionality is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

You can load ESRI JSON in QGIS, from there just resave in any format you want.
If you have the local file you can just add it as vector through the `Data Source Manager`,
QGIS will notice it's ESRI JSON:

[image]

You can also use load it straight from the server with using a query url in the `Protocol: HTTP(S). cloud, etc.` Source type:

[image]

Saving to GeoJSON from here is as simple as:

#### 1.

[image]

#### 2.

[image]