# What URL to use when exporting data from an ArcGIS MapServer layer to GeoJSON using ogr2ogr?

Tags: qgis, geojson, ogr2ogr, arcgis-rest-api

I found an ArcGIS REST MapServer showing data I care about:

https://kart.ra.no/arcgis/rest/services/Distribusjon/Kulturminner20180301/MapServer

---

### QGIS

I can visualize it in QGIS: `Layer` -> `Add Layer` -> `ArcGIS REST Server`, then create a connection with the above URL. When I connect, I am presented with multiple options:

[image]

I choose `Enkeltminner`, as that's what I care about now. I can then export data to GeoJSON:

[image]

---

### ogr2ogr

I would like to achieve this using `ogr2ogr`. Using [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13029/converting-arcgis-server-json-to-geojson), I tried:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON test.json "https://kart.ra.no/arcgis/rest/services/Distribusjon/Kulturminner20180301/MapServer/" OGRGeoJSON
```

Resulting in:

```
ERROR 4: Failed to read TopoJSON data
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `https://kart.ra.no/arcgis/rest/services/Distribusjon/Kulturminner20180301/MapServer/' with the following drivers.
  -> `FITS'
  -> `PCIDSK'
  -> `netCDF'
  -> `PDS4'
  -> `VICAR'
 ...
```

[This website](https://toolkit.data.wa.gov.au/hc/en-gb/articles/115000819754-How-To-Download-Geospatial-Data-using-GDAL-and-ogr2ogr) also provides an example of how to perform a similar task:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON CadastreAddress_Example1.json "https://services.slip.wa.gov.au/public/rest/services/SLIP_Public_Services/Property_and_Planning_WFS/MapServer/50/query?where=locality_name+%3D+%27PERTH%27&outfields=*&f=json" OGRGeoJSON -s_srs EPSG:3857 -t_srs EPSG:4326
```

Both [the answer I followed](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13029/converting-arcgis-server-json-to-geojson), and this above example uses a query string after the core URL. I think if I did figure out the correct URL, I could export the `Enkeltminner` layer to GeoJSON.

I can click [`Enkeltminneikoner`](https://kart.ra.no/arcgis/rest/services/Distribusjon/Kulturminner20180301/MapServer/6) on [the ArcGIS page I am using](https://kart.ra.no/arcgis/rest/services/Distribusjon/Kulturminner20180301/MapServer), to get to this URL (notice the `/6` in the end):

```
https://kart.ra.no/arcgis/rest/services/Distribusjon/Kulturminner20180301/MapServer/6
```

Try again with this URL:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON test.json "https://kart.ra.no/arcgis/rest/services/Distribusjon/Kulturminner20180301/MapServer/6" OGRGeoJSON
```

Output again:

```
ERROR 4: Failed to read TopoJSON data
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `https://kart.ra.no/arcgis/rest/services/Distribusjon/Kulturminner20180301/MapServer/6' with the following drivers.
  -> `FITS'
  -> `PCIDSK'
  -> `netCDF'
  -> `PDS4'
  -> `VICAR'
...
```

As suggested in the comments, I also tried:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON test.json "https://kart.ra.no/arcgis/rest/services/Distribusjon/Kulturminner20180301/MapServer/6/query?where1=1&outFields=*&f=json" OGRGeoJSON
```

This attempt seems like a closer attempt to the examples. Output however is:

```
ERROR 1: Invalid FeatureCollection object. Missing 'fields' member.
ERROR 1: Layer schema generation failed.
ERROR 4: Failed to read ESRIJSON data
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `https://kart.ra.no/arcgis/rest/services/Distribusjon/Kulturminner20180301/MapServer/6/query?where1=1&outFields=*&f=json' with the following drivers.
  -> `FITS'
  -> `PCIDSK'
  -> `netCDF'
  -> `PDS4'
  -> `VICAR'
  ...
```

It complains about `fields` member. I try replacing the `outFields` to `fields` then:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON test.json "https://kart.ra.no/arcgis/rest/services/Distribusjon/Kulturminner20180301/MapServer/6/query?where1=1&fields=*&f=json" OGRGeoJSON
```

The same error is returned.

---

### ogrinfo

It was also suggested in the comments to use this command:

```
ogrinfo -so "https://kart.ra.no/arcgis/rest/services/Distribusjon/Kulturminner20180301/MapServer/6/query?where=1=1&outFields=*&outSR=4326&f=geojson" OGRGeoJSON
```

This outputs:

```
INFO: Open of `https://kart.ra.no/arcgis/rest/services/Distribusjon/Kulturminner20180301/MapServer/6/query?where=1=1&outFields=*&outSR=4326&f=geojson'
      using driver `GeoJSON' successful.

Layer name: OGRGeoJSON
Geometry: Polygon
Feature Count: 381014
Extent: (-8.940364, 56.715905) - (33.502886, 80.821061)
Layer SRS WKT:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
kulturminneDatering: String (0.0)
kulturminneDateringKvalitet: String (0.0)
kulturminneDateringMetode: String (0.0)
kulturminneEnkeltminneArt: String (0.0)
kulturminneHovedMateriale: String (0.0)
kulturminneKategori: String (0.0)
kulturminneNavaerendeFunksjon: String (0.0)
kulturminneOpprinneligFunksjon: String (0.0)
kulturminneSynlig: Integer (0.0)
matrikkelnummer: String (0.0)
navn: String (0.0)
tilleggsvernedato: String (0.0)
tilleggsvernetype: String (0.0)
vernedato: String (0.0)
vernelov: String (0.0)
verneparagraf: String (0.0)
vernetype: String (0.0)
datafangstdato: String (0.0)
forsteDigitaliseringsdato: String (0.0)
lokalId: String (0.0)
navnerom: String (0.0)
versjonId: String (0.0)
informasjon: String (0.0)
kommune: String (0.0)
malemetode: String (0.0)
noyaktighet: Integer (0.0)
linkAskeladden: String (0.0)
linkKulturminnesok: String (0.0)
oppdateringsdato: String (0.0)
opphav: String (0.0)
OBJECTID: Integer (0.0)
SHAPE.STArea(): Real (0.0)
SHAPE.STLength(): Real (0.0)
```

which is nice, but I was aiming for a GeoJSON with the data.

---

**What URL should I use so that I can export the `Enkeltminner` layer using `ogr2ogr`, or other command line methods?**

Comment: You're trying to export the service and not a layer.  Even if a MapServer service has only one layer, you would need to include the index value in the URL to that specific layer.  I am unable to load the URL to get you that number, but note how your example includes the `/50` in the path.  That is the layer index.  Add that to your URL and try again.

Comment: Thank you! I edited my question to include an attempt like this.

Comment: You probably need to convert the output to JSON and you need features, which would be included in a query, hence why the examples use them.  Try using the following command: `ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON test.json "https://kart.ra.no/arcgis/rest/services/Distribusjon/Kulturminner20180301/MapServer/6/query?where1=1&outFields=*&f=json" OGRGeoJSON`

Comment: `ogrinfo -so "https://kart.ra.no/arcgis/rest/services/Distribusjon/Kulturminner20180301/MapServer/6/query?where=1=1&outFields=*&outSR=4326&f=geojson" OGRGeoJSON` works for me

Comment: @evv_gis, thanks, questions is updated with your suggestions.

Comment: @nmtoken, that command run for me without errors, but it did not produce a GeoJSON. Did it do that for you?

Comment: It provides a summary of the data `-so`   I assume you would want: `ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON test.json "https://kart.ra.no/arcgis/rest/services/Distribusjon/Kulturminner20180301/MapServer/6/query?where=1=1&outFields=*&outSR=4326&f=geojson" OGRGeoJSON`

Comment: This seems to work. Would you like to add it as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON test.json "https://kart.ra.no/arcgis/rest/services/Distribusjon/Kulturminner20180301/MapServer/6/query?where=1=1&outFields=*&outSR=4326&f=geojson" OGRGeoJSON
```

Comment: This is not my field, but just out of curiosity: what is this funny `where=1=1` query parameter?

Comment: @TomazicM that is just to return True, to return every row in db to the query.