Is there an easy way to generate a 2D world map from a Google Maps Timeline JSON file?
Google Maps just turned off location history access from its WEB version. So I can no longer easily get a 2D world map showing where I have been. I was able to export all of my Google Maps Data (just over 80Gb -- I got my first Google phone in 2013), and the Timeline.JSON file is just over 130 Mb. Germini (Google's LLM) suggests I need to write some code to convert that JSON file into a "GeoJSON" file. Does that sound correct? Has anyone written such code?

ogr2ogr can read your json and write geojson (if the structure of the file is correct) https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/13032/276

OGR cant read this json.

Thank you @Mapperz for this advice! Cheers!
